# Sharing SharePoint Lists across sites without SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

The problem I've been having is how to show a list from one sub-site to another. I don't have server admin privileges so I am unable to use SharePoint Designer to edit any part of the site.

The situation:
One parent page with two sub-sites.
sub-site #1 has a list on it with several text columns, and one column to be used as a 'visible' column.
sub-site #2 has to show a view of the list on sub-site #1 filtering on the 'visible' column

The two solutions I've found are to create a linked list in SharePoint Designer directly, or use a Content Query Web Part, edit the part to show the correct columns, and use SharePoint Designer to edit the item style to actually display the proper information.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a cutom webpart for fetching the data from the specified list? And you can add it where ever you want.

Comment: I've gone to look up Custom Webparts, but all the tutorials want me to  drop the dll file in the bin folder of the SharePoint site, and add it to the site's webpart gallery, but without server admin privileges I can't accomplish either goal.  
Also, I didn't make it clear in the question but I'd like to link up several lists and the calendars as well and would rather not have to write a custom web part for calendars...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Server Admin privs to use SharePoint Designer (unless the Farm administrators locked down Designer access).

One potential approach to solving the problem would be to use the RSS or XML Web Parts to syndicate content from one list to be displayed in another part of the site.  The watch out for this is that your site needs to either be accessible anonymously or is setup to do Kerberos authentication.

While we are on that topic, if you were so inclined you could make calls to the Lists Web Service for JavaScript that is delivered to the client via a Content Editor Web Part.  You'd have to do all the heavy lifting of retrieving and displaying the content but it almost undoubtedly would be something that isn't blocked in your target environment.